# Prevent parallel lookup to an oracle sequence

Tags: php, linux, oracle, fork

I have some code that selects the next # in sequence from an Oracle DB:

```
SELECT JOB_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
```

The problem is that this generates an [ORA-00900](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00900.php) (which is not helpful because the real issue is due to parallelism, NOT an invalid SQL statement). This error occurs when, at exact same moment, two scripts that are run in parallel (by method of forking) try to run this query.

What is the easiest way to ensure that the selects don't happen at the same time? I

The stack I'm working with is PHP / Linux. I have read about messaging queues and would prefer to avoid that route if possible. If something like Unix sockets could work (i.e., no additional software to deploy), then I would prefer that way.

Comment: The whole point of sequences is to provide unique values to multiple concurrent threads.  It strikes me as highly unlikely that calling `nextval` simultaneously in multiple sessions would throw an error let alone an ORA-00900 error.  If that were the case, a vast number of systems would be broken.  I suppose you might have encountered a bug in the database that would be worth searching Metalink or raising a ticket with support to resolve.  But I'd put my money on the fact that your application has a concurrency bug that is causing an invalid SQL statement to be generated.

Comment: As I understand it, forking copies all resources and file descriptors. So technically, the select happens from the same session shared by both processes. A simple way to test this theory is to issue a reconnect statement in the forked processes to guarantee that they have their own session . I'll try that now.

Comment: Ok so a quick follow up here. Thanks for explaining that sequences work from multiple sessions. I ran a few tests after issuing a reconnect (so that all child processes have their own sessions to the Oracle Database), and it works as expected. Shall I provide a write up below, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  If you have an answer, it would be helpful to add it for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue lies in the nature of forking and how Oracle sessions work.

If you fork a process, you must ensure that your database sessions in the child processes are **different.**

When you try to select a sequence from the same Oracle session either OCI or the database itself does not know how to deal with this.

But, if the sessions are different, you have no issues. This can be done simply by issuing an oci_close() and oci_connect() if you are using the oci8 extension in PHP.

EDIT: Credit to [Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave) (commented above) for explaining that selecting sequences works across different sessions.